# android get context of fragment in activity

Tags: java, android, fragment

I want to get the context or instance of fragment in a activity.I tried following code：
In fragment:

```
public static XXFragment instance;
```

In the onCreate():

```
instance = this;
```

In activity:

```
Context context = XXFrangment.instance;
```

But it has NullPointerException error.Because I haven't invoked onCreate() of fragment.So how can I do to get the context or instance of Fragment?Hope somebody could help me!

Comment: Fragment doesn't have a context. What are you trying to do?

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: 1) getting `this` instance of Fragment means getting the context of the Activity on which the Fragment is attached.
2) If you haven't even created the Fragment how can you expect to get it's (Activity's) context?

Comment: I got it,Thanks for your answering.new hand. excuse me:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is some error in your way of thinking about `Context` :-)

First of all, `Fragment` does not have a `Context` until added to an `Activity`. After it is added, the `Activity` itself is it's Context, so there is no need to extract it from the `Fragment`. Just use `this` in `Activity` code :-)

As a side note, avoid static fields holding complex objects such as `Fragments` and `Activities`. In a real, production environment you will never do this, as it leads to so called **memory leaks**, a big problem in software.

Comment: but if I want to invoke this function:`public boolean FragmentmayRequestSD(final Fragment fragment)`and when it was called is like this:`public boolean onPreferenceTreeClick(PreferenceScreen preferenceScreen, Preference preference) {
                if (mayRequest.FragmentmayRequestSD(this)`,the "this"there

Comment: What function? :-)

Comment: what is the "this" there? If I want to invoke the function in another activity.How should I do?

Comment: Ok, I understand, but then what is this in your question:

Context context = XXFrangment.instance;

Comment: In fact what I use is like this:`.FragmentmayRequestSD(XXclass.XXFragment.instance`is it right?

Comment: You should not do that. You can keep the Fragment reference in the Activity if you need that, but do NOT make the Fragment a Singleton. This will break the lifecycle and make your application work wrong.

Comment: I got it,So could you show me the specific code?I really don't know how to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

It's good practice to use static method for fragment initializing. Implement this method in your fragment class:

```
public static YourFragment newInstance() {
     Bundle args = new Bundle();
     YourFragment fragment = new YourFragment();
     fragment.setArguments(args);
     return fragment;
}
```

As you can see, you are able to add parameters in a `newInstance()` method. These parameters are usually used for adding them as arguments of the fragment.